# Changing node for compute. Openstack kilo release ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: 14.04, openstack, nova

I have 3 nodes: controller, compute1 and network.

Unfortunately network had 72 GB RAM and compute only 16. I wanted to change them

Installed fresh Ubuntu 14.04 on each of them (controller haven't touched).

After installing nova-compute and making proper setting it cannot connect to rabbitmq.
I've recreated database for nova. Not helped.
Error is that Compute host compute1 cannot be found.

Do I need to change something in rabbitmq-server or smth else on controller node?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:

[Keystone connection fail | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844010/keystone-connection-fail?newreg=df06611709234b95871e244e6f88762d)

The problem is that developers changed repositories for some components and you need to add them to every node.....